# Fitting a particular Gaussian model

Tags: r, mixed-model, sas, multiple-regression

Using R or SAS, I want to fit the following Gaussian model:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
y_{1j1} \\ y_{1j2} \\ y_{1j3} \\ y_{2j1} \\ y_{2j2} \\ y_{2j3}
\end{pmatrix}
\sim_{\text{i.i.d.}} 
 {\cal N}
 \left( 
 \begin{pmatrix} 
\mu_1 \\
\mu_1  \\ 
\mu_1 \\
\mu_2 \\
\mu_2  \\ 
\mu_2 
 \end{pmatrix}
 , \Sigma \right), j=1, \ldots n
$$
with covariance matrix having the following structure:
$$
\Sigma = 
\begin{pmatrix}
\Sigma_0 & M \\
M & \Sigma_0 
\end{pmatrix}
$$
with $\Sigma_0$ a "compound symmetry" (exchangeable) covariance matrix and $M=\delta \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$, $\delta \in \mathbb{R}$. 
Importantly, I need a general exchangeable matrix $\Sigma_0$, with possibly negative correlation.

EDIT: In view of some comments (and even an answer) given below I should add a precision: I am not a beginner with PROC MIXED in SAS and nlme in R, and I know how to consult the documentations. But in spite of my experience I am not able to fit this model.

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: Obviously the question is: how to fit such a model with R or SAS ?

Comment: So you wish to estimate a covariance matrix $\Sigma_0$ based on two dependent vectors with known inter-covariances. Is $\delta$ known?

Comment: All parameters are unknown.

Comment: There probably is a pre-existing package in R to fit this model (look into covariance structure models) but I don't know what it is - this seems more like the business of MPLUS. In any case, you can write down the likelihood, code it into R and maximize it using `optim` :)

Comment: I have look the nlme package but I have not find a way to specify such a correlation structure. I do not only need estimates of the parameters, but also the standard errors (for estimates of the means). Moreover I'm working in a private company, it is preferable to use a software.

Comment: I was trying to code it in R but I am intrigued because this covariance structure is not a positive definite matrix. For example if $\Sigma_0=I_3$ and $\delta=1$, then $\vert \Sigma\vert = -8$.

Comment: Thanks for this remark. Some restrictions are required on $\delta$.

Comment: So the standard `corCompSymm` for `nlme` does have the correct $\Sigma_0$ term but not 1 as $M$ and you want to know how to set $M$ to 1?

Answer (score 1):

I think you may have to go for direct optimisation of the loglikelihood, especially if you want to allow negative correlations in the diagonal block. At least in R; I don't speak SAS.

I would follow what `lme4` does in profiling out the $\mu$ terms and an overall scale factor and then feeding the -2 log profile likelihood to `minqa::bobyqa`, which is a fast, derivative-free optimiser for smooth functions.  That's what I've done for composite-likelihood mixed models.

The profile likelihood calculations are in the `lme4` "Computational Methods" vignette.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't told us how many data points you have.  You need a certain number for the parameters to be estimable.  I don't think that SAS has a proc that fits multivariate distributions per se but if you were using proc mixed and y is in the model  these parameters would be calculated and could be printed out. You would have to specify the covariance structure.

Comment: The question is: how to specify this covariance structure ?